# Setup cronjobs to different time zones in same server

Tags: server, cron, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-18.04

I want to set up cronjobs in the same ubuntu 18 server but for different timezones.

For example, I wanted to send a notification to every UK user at 9 a.m. and the same notification should be triggered to US users at 9 a.m. according to their timezone.

I tried the implementation below but it is not working. Still those notifications are triggered in UTC timezones.
Is there any way to achieve this? 3rd party service is also fine.

```
CRON_TZ = 'Europe/London'

0 9 * * * curl --silent https://example.com/checkUk

CRON_TZ = 'America/New_York'

0 9 * * * curl --silent https://example.com/checkUs
```

Comment: No, that is not working. Still, those jobs got executed according to the UTC timezone.

Comment: Follow this [doc](https://linuxhint.com/set-timezone-crontab/) and create two cron jobs separately  for UK and US users. Might help you in resolving this case, if not resolved post the errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set different timezone for your particular cronjob, execute crontab -e via ssh and add

```
TZ=America/New_York
```

before every cronjob.

Refer this [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49810321/how-to-run-cron-on-same-time-in-different-time-zones) which might help you .

Comment: Downvote. Clearly the question is about the timezone for the *scheduling* of the jobs, not their execution.